# How does PHP compare a non numeric string to an integer?

Tags: php

I'm trying to use this code to print a text based on $num variable value, but when I assign a non-numeric value to it the output is much like I assigned a positive number, shouldn't the output here be 'Undefined Value'? I mean why isn't executing the default case?

```
$num = ";";
match (true) {
    $num < 0 => print 'negative number',
    $num == 0 => print 'zero',
    $num > 0 => print 'positive number',
    default => 'Undefined Value',
};
//Output: positive number
```

Comment: Perhaps add a check to see if `$num` is numeric using [is_numeric](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)?

Comment: var_dump(is_numeric($num)); //bool(false)                I tried to use it but it's returning false which means it knows it isn't a numeric value, yet it is being evaluated as if it was a number.

Comment: @executable if `;` is converted to `0`, then branch `$num == 0` should be executed, isn't it?

Comment: `$num` value is being evaluated the way you tell it. And you tell it to compare value with zero. There's __no branch__ that checks if value is numeric.

Comment: Just in case, there is no print at the default value so you will not see it even if you change the previous conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler test case:

```
var_dump(';' > 0);
```

```
bool(true)
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/4ppEg#v8.2.11)

If we check [how comparison operators work](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.types), we understand that both operators are converted to numbers, but that isn't true any more starting on PHP/8.0:

```
var_dump(';' > 0, (int)';', (int)';' > 0, (float)';', (float)';' > 0);
```

```
bool(true)
int(0)
bool(false)
float(0)
bool(false)
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/op48i)

I suspect that documentation needs a fix and current rules are that right side operator is cast to string. As such, `;` is `3B` in ASCII and `0` is `30` (thus "smaller").

Regarding your code, you could add a numeric check like this:

```
match (true) {
    is_numeric($num) && $num < 0 => print 'negative number',
    is_numeric($num) && $num == 0 => print 'zero',
    is_numeric($num) && $num > 0 => print 'positive number',
    default => 'Undefined Value',
};
```

But perhaps (and bear in mind that this is pretty much subjective) a match expression does not provide the leanest syntax for this use case and good old set of if/else can to the work just as fine. You can easily call `is_numeric()` once and avoid IEEE precision errors:

```
if (!is_numeric($num)) {
    print 'Undefined Value';
} elseif ($num < 0) {
    print 'negative number';
} elseif ($num > 0) {
    print 'negative number';
} else {
    print 'zero';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this and it worked:

```
    $num = ";";
    is_numeric($num) ? match (true) {
    $num < 0 => print 'negative number',
    $num == 0 => print 'zero',
    $num > 0 => print 'positive number',
    }
    : print "Undefined Value";
    //Output: Undefined Value
```